# Laravel Homestead: 'php artisan serve' not working

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, homestead, serve

When I run the command `php artisan serve` in the directory /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/ it appears to work. (/Laravel is my project directory)
[Screenshot of Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8SvJ.png)

But when I open up localhost:8000 in the browser, I get this:
[Error Page Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqI7C.png)

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Did you edit your hosts file, per the documentation? https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/homestead#installation-and-setup

Comment: The OP can't comment because he doesn't have enough rep points

Comment: @Simon Richard try to figure  out what is the IP address of your vagrant machine and then run this command: `php -S 192.168.*.*:8000 -t public` instead of php artisan serve it should be more descriptive and you will know if something is wrong

Comment: You're running `php artisan serve` within the Homestead Vagrant box. You can't access that via `localhost`.

Comment: I did edit the hosts file.  Here's what I got when I ran php -S ...

Comment: vagrant@homestead:~/Code/Laravel$ php -S 10.0.2.15:8000 -t public
PHP 7.1.0-2+deb.sury.org~xenial+1 Development Server started at Wed Jan  4 21:25:53 2017
Listening on http://10.0.2.15:8000
Document root is /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public
Press Ctrl-C to quit.

Comment: Using a different ip (the one specified in Homestead.yaml):   vagrant@homestead:~/Code/Laravel$ php -S 192.168.10.10:8000 -t public
[Wed Jan  4 21:29:34 2017] Failed to listen on 192.168.10.10:8000 (reason: Cannot assign requested address)

Comment: It did not work for either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled vagrant, virtualbox, and homestead, and then ran `vagrant up` in ~/Homestead instead of ~/Code.  This worked.

Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running a homestead/vagrant box, hey would you use php artisan serve? Homestead ist starting a virtual box with apache, php, mysql... there ist no need for artisan serve... just add the IP of the box (specified in the Homestead.yaml file) and the domain name to your /etc/hosts file.